# Jenkins with jFrog Artifactory push Docker images

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to configure new pipeline in Jenkins. I have purchased and installed jFrog artifactory pro on Windows Server and it's up and running at: https://artifactory.mycompany.com

I found this sample here:
https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/docker-push-example/Jenkinsfile

More specifically this section:

```
stage ('Push image to Artifactory') {
        steps {
            rtDockerPush(
                serverId: "ARTIFACTORY_SERVER",
                image: ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY + '/hello-world:latest',
                // Host:
                // On OSX: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1234"
                // On Linux can be omitted or null
                host: HOST_NAME,
                targetRepo: 'docker-local',
                // Attach custom properties to the published artifacts:
                properties: 'project-name=docker1;status=stable'
            )
        }
    }
```

It's building and creating docker image but when it gets to push image it fails to push the image and errors out. Not sure what should go in the following:

- ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY
- host: HOST_NAME

I've created a new local repo in artifactory "docker-local". Tried omitting host and getting

> "Unsupported OS".

Putting host back in with "host: 'tcp://IP ADDRESSS" or "artifactory.mycompany.com:80/artifactory" generates

> "Unsupported protocol scheme"

How would one configure jenkins pipeline to work with jFrog artifactory?

Comment: What error is being returned?

Comment: @MattSchuchard i've listed those above. Not sure what value to use in "Host" and "ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY". is "ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY" expected name of Local-docker registry?

Comment: So that code appears to use more recent global var methods. The older class methods always worked consistently for me. You may have run into a bug since this is supported under a new major release.

Comment: @MattSchuchard can you please let me know what values should be populated for those variables? What should go in HOST_NAME & ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

- ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REGISTRY should be IP/Artifactory-Repo-Key/Image:Tag
- HOST should be docker daemon (Docker for windows is localhost:2375)

  ```
      stage('Build image') { // build and tag docker image
          steps {
              echo 'Starting to build docker image'

              script {
                  def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile'
                  def customImage = docker.build('10.20.111.23:8081/docker-virtual/hello-world:latest', "-f ${dockerfile} .")

              }
          }
      }

      stage ('Push image to Artifactory') { // take that image and push to artifactory
          steps {
              rtDockerPush(
                  serverId: "jFrog-ar1",
                  image: "10.20.111.23:8081/docker-virtual/hello-world:latest",
                  host: 'tcp://localhost:2375',
                  targetRepo: 'local-repo', // where to copy to (from docker-virtual)
                  // Attach custom properties to the published artifacts:
                  properties: 'project-name=docker1;status=stable'
              )
          }
      }
  ```