# How do I get a Jenkins Agent to pull its Docker image from Artifactory?

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory

I have a docker agent setup under the "Configure Clouds" page on Jenkins. It is successfully pulling bibinwilson/jenkins-slave:latest and I've done some successful test runs, but I am hitting rate limiting issues so I would like to pull from Artifactory or anywhere other than docker-hub. I have already pushed the image to Artifactory from my server, however I do not know how to configure the Jenkins Agent to pull from Artifactory.

Is this possibly something that would be configured under configureClouds>docker_agent_templates>container_settings>Docker_Command on Jenkins? Or maybe I am supposed to change some settings on the docker server? Please help.

Comment: There are examples available in the JFrog's Github, kindly refer to https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/docker-pull-example/Jenkinsfile and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203820/jenkins-with-jfrog-artifactory-push-docker-images

Comment: This uses a node any, and there doesn't appear anything on those pages about setting up a docker agent on either of these pages. I am capable of pulling and pushing images, but I do not know how to force the docker agent to pull it's image from a specific place other than the docker-hub. Is it possible?