# Confusion about pushing Docker images to Artifactory in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory

When pushing a Docker image to Artifactory from Jenkins, using the JFrog plugin, both the [scripted](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-DockerBuildswithArtifactory) and [declarative](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-DockerBuildswithArtifactory) syntax expect an `image` and a `targetRepo` parameter. The documentation isn't overly clear what these should be, but a little playing around seems to suggest:

- `image`: The Artifactory image tag, including the Artifactory registry URL (e.g., `artifactory.example.com/my-docker-registry/my-image:latest`)
- `targetRepo`: The tag of the image that was built locally to Jenkins that you want to push (e.g., `my-image:SOME_GIT_COMMIT`).

However, this *only* seems to work if you explicitly retag your image first. Otherwise it complains with an "Image not found" error:

```
stage("Push image to Artifactory") {
  steps {
    // Step 1: Retag the built image with the Artifactory repository tag
    sh "docker tag ${tag} ${artifactory_tag}"

    // Step 2: Push the newly tagged image
    rtDockerPush (
      serverId: artifactory_server,
      image: artifactory_tag,
      targetRepo: tag
    )

    // Step 3: Publish the build info
    rtPublishBuildInfo (
      serverId: artifactory_server
    )
  }
}
```

Why do I have to retag the image, since all the information is available to `rtDockerPush`; why can't it do the retagging? Or, alternatively, does `targetRepo` not mean what I think it means, despite it seeming to work under my assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

`targetRepo` is the repository in Artifactory where we would like to push the image to. Please check if a definition like the below in the pipeline is helpful to simplify both tagging and target configuration in the same step?

```
def buildInfo = rtDocker.push '<artifactoryDockerRegistry>/hello-world:latest', '<targetRepo>'
```

Also, please check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226421/12378094) is useful, that includes a working pipeline example.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the Artifactory repository and the Artifactory Docker registry? For example, if I want to push `artifactory.example.com/my-docker-registry/my-image:latest` then isn't the Artifactory repository `my-docker-registry`? That would be redundant, so I suspect my understanding is completely wrong...